# СПП союзное слово

Tags: союзы, спп

Определите часть речи и синтаксическую функцию слов, присоединяющих придаточные в каждом предложении.

Так играл пред землёй молодою Одарённый один режиссёр, Что носился как дух над водою И ребро сокрушённое тёр (Пастернак).

1. Союз
2. Относительное местоимение, дополнение
3. Относительное местоимение, подлежащее
4. Относительное местоимение, определение

Comment: Пожалуйста, предлагайте свой вариант,  в противном случае участникам отвечать не рекомендуется (это будет выполнение домашнего задания).

Comment: Vera буду указывать свой вариант. Просто не знала об этом условии. Использую приложение в качестве проверки точности моего ответа. Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 1):

Относительное местоимение, подлежащее

Comment: Серж, если "что" в придаточном дополнение, то что в этом придаточном является подлежащим?

Comment: А, да, спутался.Спасибо. Здесь действительно подлежащее.